# Principle of locality for object-key data pairs

Tags: cpu-cache, object-oriented, applications

It seems that if we only have object-key cache then we won't have spatial locality and only temporal locality. I use memcached in a python application and that has only object-key pairs and no hierarchy. Is this observation correct and why don't object-key caches behave more like physical cache memories where the latter have hierarchies like L1, L2, L3 etc?

Comment: spatial locality in physical cache memories is achieved through address coalescing when caching data at cache-line granularity. However in OO world, to the best of my knowledge, there is no such thing as "nearby" objects, hence could be the reason that you are not seeing spatial locality.